# When is full SVD used, if at all?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Whenever I see SVD, it's first introduced in a full form (i.e. for $X_{n \times m}$, where $n > m$, matrix $U$ has $n$ columns) and then truncated (so $U$ has $m$ columns). It's always also stated that we "almost never" use full SVD. So when would we use it, apart from theory (e.g. having orthgonal $U$ for proofs)? Or even in theory, where would we use full SVD instead of reduced?

Comment: The only setting in which the full SVD would be preferred is in the "theoretical" setting. In this setting, the full SVD is indeed strongly preferred. For example, if you look up proofs of the [EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation), pretty much all of them use the full SVD because it is much easier to work with an orthogonal $U$ that with a $U$ for which we only have $U^TU = I$ (for the $n>m$ case)

Comment: @BenGrossmann I suspected so, post the comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Apparently you have found the answer you wanted but it has nothing to do with the question you wrote(which, as I read, potential uses apart in theory or uses of the truncated version in theory). Can you edit so your real question appears in the text ? @qalis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only setting in which the full SVD would be preferred is in the "theoretical" setting. In this setting, the full SVD is indeed strongly preferred. For example, if you look up proofs of the [EYM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation), pretty much all of them use the full SVD because it is much easier to work with an orthogonal $U$ that with a $U$ for which we only have $U^TU = I$ (for the $n>m$ case)